# Coverting old js project to webpack npm getting error like Cannot read property 'className' of null

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am converting old codekit project into webpack. I almost there but getting strange error when using [scrollReveal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scrollreveal) which I never got before.

There is error seems purely javascript related tho...

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of null`

This is the usage which is currently worked on the old site.

```
// scroll reveal
const ScrollReveal = require('scrollreveal');


// jQuery
(function ($) {

    // scroll reveal profile listings
    if (!/(?:^|\s)ie\-[6-9](?:$|\s)/.test(document.body.className)) {
        window.sr = new ScrollReveal({reset: false});
        sr.reveal('[data-reveal="true"]', {duration: 1000});
    }

})(jQuery);
```

What I am doing is testing the body class with some regex to make sure [scrollReveal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scrollreveal) does not fire in IE 6-9.

Everything compiles fine, it's just i'm getting error in the console log and no scrollReveal.

Any ideas would be great thanks.

Comment: `document.body` is null? When does this code run?

Comment: Ah yes I have moved this script into the `<head>` to include jquery as on file. I guess it's firing too early then. But i'm using this inside `(function ($) {` which i thought was doc ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a wrapper around your code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  // scroll reveal
  const ScrollReveal = require('scrollreveal');

  // scroll reveal profile listings
  if (!/(?:^|\s)ie\-[6-9](?:$|\s)/.test(document.body.className)) {
    window.sr = new ScrollReveal({reset: false});
    sr.reveal('[data-reveal="true"]', {duration: 1000});
  } 
});
```

Comment: Ah nice one dude that works sweet. Thank you so much, I will use for any other pure js stuff too. Will accept answer in 5